# How to write the contents of a treeview to a text file

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have constructed a TreeView with varying levels of parent and child nodes.

My challenge now is that I do not know how to write the contents of my TreeView to a text file. I would also like to be able to read the text file to again re-populate my TreeView.

How can I go about this?

Any ideas and/or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways that you could accomplish this but I believe the best way would be to save the treeview nodes as binary data to a flat file and read it back when you need it.

Here is a simple example. You can create a new vb.net winforms project and just copy/paste this code over the code for `Form1` and click 'Run':

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim tv As New TreeView
    Dim cmdSave As New Button
    Dim cmdClear As New Button
    Dim cmdLoad As New Button

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Setup control positions and values

        tv.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        tv.Size = New Size(Me.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height - cmdSave.Height)
        cmdSave.Location = New Point(0, Me.ClientSize.Height - cmdSave.Height)
        cmdSave.Text = "Save"
        AddHandler cmdSave.Click, AddressOf cmdSave_Click
        cmdClear.Location = New Point(cmdSave.Left + cmdSave.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height - cmdClear.Height)
        cmdClear.Text = "Clear"
        AddHandler cmdClear.Click, AddressOf cmdClear_Click
        cmdLoad.Location = New Point(cmdClear.Left + cmdClear.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height - cmdLoad.Height)
        cmdLoad.Text = "Load"
        AddHandler cmdLoad.Click, AddressOf cmdLoad_Click

        ' Build the treeview

        tv.Nodes.Add("Node 1")
        tv.Nodes(tv.Nodes.Count - 1).Nodes.Add("Node 1 - Child 1")
        tv.Nodes(tv.Nodes.Count - 1).Nodes.Add("Node 1 - Child 2")
        tv.Nodes(tv.Nodes.Count - 1).Nodes.Add("Node 1 - Child 3")
        tv.Nodes.Add("Node 2")
        tv.Nodes(tv.Nodes.Count - 1).Nodes.Add("Node 2 - Child 1")
        tv.Nodes(tv.Nodes.Count - 1).Nodes.Add("Node 2 - Child 2")
        tv.Nodes(tv.Nodes.Count - 1).Nodes.Add("Node 2 - Child 3")

        tv.ExpandAll()

        ' Add controls to the form

        Me.Controls.Add(tv)
        Me.Controls.Add(cmdSave)
        Me.Controls.Add(cmdClear)
        Me.Controls.Add(cmdLoad)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Try
            Dim dlg As New SaveFileDialog

            dlg.DefaultExt = "sav"
            dlg.Filter = "sav files|*.sav"
            dlg.OverwritePrompt = True

            If dlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                ' Save the treeview nodes to file

                Dim oTreeList As New List(Of clsTreeFile)

                For Each oNode As TreeNode In tv.Nodes
                    Dim oTree As New clsTreeFile

                    oTree.oTreeNode = oNode
                    oTreeList.Add(oTree)
                Next

                Using oFileStream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open(dlg.FileName, IO.FileMode.Create)
                    Dim oBinaryFormatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
                    oBinaryFormatter.Serialize(oFileStream, oTreeList)
                End Using

                MessageBox.Show("Treeview saved successfully.", "File saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while saving:" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        tv.Nodes.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog

        Try
            dlg.DefaultExt = "sav"
            dlg.Filter = "SAV files|*.sav"

            If dlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                ' Open saved file and read the binary data back to the treeview

                tv.Nodes.Clear()

                Dim oTreeList As New List(Of clsTreeFile)

                Using oFileStream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open(dlg.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open)
                    Dim oBinaryFormatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
                    oTreeList = CType(oBinaryFormatter.Deserialize(oFileStream), List(Of clsTreeFile))
                End Using

                For Each oNode As clsTreeFile In oTreeList
                    tv.Nodes.Add(oNode.oTreeNode)
                Next

                tv.ExpandAll()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("The " & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName) & " file cannot be opened." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error opening file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class clsTreeFile
    Public oTreeNode As TreeNode
End Class
```

Comment: This is very useful to me and I will try it out and let you know how it does.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. This runs perfectly. A few tweaks here and there and I was able to modify it to fit nicely into my application. Thank you once again. You have helped me a lot.